# PHP and MySQL login system how to make code more clean

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, authentication

I have decided to recently make a login system which runs through mysql on vb.net but I am collecting the mysql information thought PHP because then people cant look around in my code and find the mysql username and password.

Here is my php code

cryption.php:

```
<?php
$rijnKey = "\x1\x2\x3\x4\x5\x6\x7\x8\x9\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16";
$rijnIV = "\x1\x2\x3\x4\x5\x6\x7\x8\x9\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16";
function Decrypt($s){
global $rijnKey, $rijnIV;

if ($s == "") { return $s; }

// Turn the cipherText into a ByteArray from Base64
try {
$s = str_replace("BIN00101011BIN", "+", $s);
$s = base64_decode($s);
$s = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $rijnKey, $s, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $rijnIV);
} catch(Exception $e) {
// There is a problem with the string, perhaps it has bad base64 padding
// Do Nothing
}
return $s;
}

function Encrypt($s){
global $rijnKey, $rijnIV;

// Have to pad if it is too small
$block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 'cbc');
$pad = $block - (strlen($s) % $block);
$s .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

$s = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $rijnKey, $s, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $rijnIV);
$s = base64_encode($s);
$s = str_replace("+", "BIN00101011BIN", $s);
return $s;
}
?>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
include_once("cryption.php");
include_once("db_conx.php");
if(isset($_GET['login'])){
  $login = $_GET['login'];
  $login = explode("§", $login);
  $user = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, Decrypt($login[0]));
  $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, Decrypt($login[1]));
  $pass = md5(sha1($pass));
  $user = str_replace('', '', $user);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = '".$user."' AND pass = '".$pass."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $rows['hash'];
  } else {
    echo 'no';
  }
} else {
  echo "no";
}
?>
```

Here is my vb.net code.

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    ' Keys required for Symmetric encryption / decryption
    Dim rijnKey As Byte() = {&H1, &H2, &H3, &H4, &H5, &H6, &H7, &H8, &H9, &H10, &H11, &H12, &H13, &H14, &H15, &H16}
    Dim rijnIV As Byte() = {&H1, &H2, &H3, &H4, &H5, &H6, &H7, &H8, &H9, &H10, &H11, &H12, &H13, &H14, &H15, &H16}

    Function Decrypt(S As String)
        If S = "" Then
            Return S
        End If
        ' Turn the cipherText into a ByteArray from Base64
        Dim cipherText As Byte()
        Try
            ' Replace any + that will lead to the error
            cipherText = Convert.FromBase64String(S.Replace("BIN00101011BIN", "+"))
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' There is a problem with the string, perhaps it has bad base64 padding
            Return S
        End Try
        'Creates the default implementation, which is RijndaelManaged.
        Dim rijn As SymmetricAlgorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create()
        Try
            ' Create the streams used for decryption.
            Using msDecrypt As New MemoryStream(cipherText)
                Using csDecrypt As New CryptoStream(msDecrypt, rijn.CreateDecryptor(rijnKey, rijnIV), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                    Using srDecrypt As New StreamReader(csDecrypt)
                        ' Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream and place them in a string.
                        S = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch E As CryptographicException
            Return S
        End Try
        Return S
    End Function
    Function Encrypt(S As String)
        'Creates the default implementation, which is RijndaelManaged.
        Dim rijn As SymmetricAlgorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create()
        Dim encrypted() As Byte
        Using msEncrypt As New MemoryStream()
            Dim csEncrypt As New CryptoStream(msEncrypt, rijn.CreateEncryptor(rijnKey, rijnIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            Using swEncrypt As New StreamWriter(csEncrypt)
                'Write all data to the stream.
                swEncrypt.Write(S)
            End Using
            encrypted = msEncrypt.toArray()
        End Using

        ' You cannot convert the byte to a string or you will get strange characters so base64 encode the string
        ' Replace any + that will lead to the error
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted).Replace("+", "BIN00101011BIN")
    End Function
    Dim MouseDrag As Boolean
    Dim MouseX As Integer
    Dim MouseY As Integer
    Private Sub Panel2_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel2.MouseEnter
        Panel2.BackColor = Color.RosyBrown
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel2_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel2.MouseLeave
        Panel2.BackColor = Color.Turquoise
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel2_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel2.MouseDown
        Panel2.BackColor = Color.Crimson
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel2_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel2.MouseUp
        Me.Close()
        Form2.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseDown
        MouseDrag = True
        MouseX = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - Me.Left
        MouseY = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - Me.Top
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseMove
        If MouseDrag = True Then
            Me.Top = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - MouseY
            Me.Left = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - MouseX
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseUp
        MouseDrag = False
    End Sub


    Private Sub Panel6_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel6.MouseUp
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please enter a Username and Password")
        Else
            Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
            Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.mcmorcraft.info/secure/login.php?login=" + Encrypt(TextBox1.Text) + "§" + Encrypt(TextBox2.Text))
            If result = "no" Then
                MsgBox("You have entered the Incorrect Username or Password")
            Else
                Me.Hide()
                Form2.Show()
            End If

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is there anyway this code can be improved / made more secure also i am trying to find out how to remove the "$user = str_replace('', '', $user);" this removes a random char which is placed on the end of the username after I Decrypt it, strange right?

Comment: Bump I really need help with this.